# Kubernetes: running different CNI driver for different nodes?

Tags: networking, kubernetes, kubernetes-networkpolicy

Is it possible to do this: say run flannel on node{1, 2, 3} and calico on node{4, 5, 6}. Obviously, pods can only communicate within the same *network*.

Comment: Any reason why?

Answer (score 1):

The short absolute answer is yes. Considering that overlays are speaking CNI and CNI is a standard and that you may have to hack the code in the overlays so support things like a flat network space.

The practical answer is no. There are no official guides and it's not officially supported.

Comment: I think kubernetes _requires_ that all pods are on the same flat network. In this respect that would be a firm no.